# Fullcalendar performance issue on huge data

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm rendering more than 1000 events for each day in the month view. How I can optimize rendering performance ?

I'm currently use 'addEventSource' and set eventLimit, but it's not impact on performance.

**Update**

```
$("#full-calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
```

I just initialize fullcalendar and set option eventLimit : true. I got "freezing" at passing data to fullcalendar (line above).

Comment: Perhaps can you give some of your code to imagine how it looks. Then we might be able to help.

Comment: Added code example